# Scala Play Framework 2.6 - define routes consuming custom objects

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.6

In package `models` I have the following case class:

```
case class Property (id: Option[Long],
                 address: String,
                 postCode: Int,
                 latitude: Double,
                 longitude: Double,
                 surface: Option[Int],
                 bedRoomCount: Option[Int])

object Property {
    implicit val propertyFormat = Json.format[Property]
}
```

I'm trying to configure a route passing a Property object:

```
POST    /update-property            controllers.PropertyController.update(property: models.Property)
```

My controller defines an action:

```
def update(property: Property) = Action.async { implicit request =>
 ...bla bla bla...
}
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
[error] conf/routes:8:1: No QueryString binder found for type models.Property. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.
[error] POST    /update-property            controllers.PropertyController.update(property: models.Property)
[error] conf/routes:8:1: not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable[models.Property])play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable[models.Property].
[error] Unspecified value parameter e.
```

What am I missing? Is it possible to populate a form with the `property` data?

Comment: Shouldn't the package name be `models` instead of `models.Property`?

Comment: models is the package, Property.scala is the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the compile error says, you need to implement an `implicit QueryStringBindable`. Something like this:

```
object Binders {

  //return the error message on the left should the parsing fail
  private def propertyFromString(s: String): Either[String, Property] = ???

  private def propertyToString(property: Property): String = ???

  implicit def queryStringBindable(implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]): QueryStringBindable[Property] = new QueryStringBindable[Property] {
    override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Property]] = {
      for {
        eitherPropString <- stringBinder.bind("property", params)
      } yield {
        eitherPropString match {
          case Right(propString) => propertyFromString(propString)
          case _ => Left("Unable to bind property")
        }
      }
    }
    override def unbind(key: String, property: Property): String = {
      stringBinder.unbind("property", propertyToString(property))
    }
  }

}
```

For the `???`, you will need to write the code to encode/decode a `Property` to/from a `String`. Then, in your `build.sbt` file, add

```
routesImport += "path.to.Binders._"
```

such that your `routes` file has access to your `Binders` object. The documentation is [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRequestBinders). If instead you want to pass in the `Property` fields as individual query parameters, see the `AgeRange` example in the documentation.